# Cython won't compile on Windows 7 x64

Tags: python, windows-7, mingw, 64-bit, cython

I'm struggling with installing Cython on Windows 7 x64.
I downloaded and installed the `automated MinGW installer`. The created a distutils.cfg to the distutils folder with the following content:

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

After adding `C:\MinGW\bin` to the environment variables, I called `easy_install Cython` but I get the following errors. Raping the internet did really not give me helpful resulsts as all this compiling stuff *(or should I say sh*t ?)* is so new to me.

```
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x5d59): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttr'
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x5dc5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttr'
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x5e31): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttr'
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x5ebc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Call'
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x5f08): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New'
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x5f49): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_SetAttr'
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x5ffe): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x6013): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x601e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
c:\users\niklas\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-dgjjub\cython-0.15\cython\plex\scanners.o:Scanners.c:(.text+0x602d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyInt_FromLong'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'dllwrap' failed with exit status 1
```

Any ideas whats wrong ? Thanks !

**UPDATE**:
I used dlltools to create libpython27.a and then again tried to build Cython and it just worked fine !
But now, calling cython.exe delivers this error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed, %1 is not a valid Win32-executable.
```

I assume this is because I use Pythonx64 but the MinGW32 compiler ?
So, how can i compile it for x64 ?

Comment: @lance What did you change ? // ah the title.

Comment: The title. You can see a summary of revision edits by clicking on the "X mins ago" text which appears directly after the word "edited " above my avatar above.

Comment: Can I recommend just using x86 python? Tons of packages are much harder to install/find/compile for x64 and every benchmark I've seen has x64 python trailing performance. Someone explained some of the design issues with x64 python and from then on I decided that it was not ready for primetime.

Comment: Thanks, I finally changed to x86 Python and that did work ! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are pre-compiled Cython packages [on this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython). I'd suggest you to switch to x86 Python, you gain no real advantage by using the x64 version. If you want to stick with x64, you can't use MingW and you have to use MS SDK C++ compiler ([more on this](http://wiki.cython.org/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows)).

> **Do not use MinGW-w64**. As you will notice, the MinGW import library
>   for Python (e.g. libpython27.a) is omitted from the AMD64 version of
>   Python. This is deliberate.
>   Do not try to make one using dlltool.
>   [...] There have also been issues with the mingw runtime
>   conflicting with the MSVC runtime; this can happen from places you
>   don't expect, such as inside runtime libraries for g++ or gfortran.