# Python compiled error with VC++ compiler under Win 7 64bits

Tags: python, c++, cython, distutils

I download a package for devs (scikit) and when building, I did:

```
1) Git download
2) VC++ for Python: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/#comment-515
3) Change the Path for compiler
4) python setup.py build
Win 7 64bits, Python 2.7, Anaconda
```

I have this error:

```
building 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build' extension

compiling C sources

cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -ID:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda2\lib\si
te-packages\numpy\core\include -ID:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\n
umpy\core\include -ID:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda2\include -ID:\_devs\Python01\Anac
onda2\PC /Tc_check_build.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_check_build.obj


Found executable C:\Users\asus1\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C
++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe


_check_build.c
c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '_check_build.c': No such file
or directory
```

I looked in past questions and could not find anythin.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8088312/5781248) might help i.e. `set MSSdk=1` and `set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1`

Comment: Stil lhave the issues....